# Text identification

Tags: python, algorithm, text

Let's say I have a list of some strings (movie names in my case) and now I have a new sentence which contains one of the string from the list of strings. How do I find that which string does the sentence has? 
For eg:

```
list_of_strings = ['20th century women', 'green is gold ', 'fire at sea']
sentence = 'Official Trailer | Green is  gold - Releasing Tomorrow'
```

For above case, solution should be able to find that *sentence* contains *green is gold*.
Please suggest which algorithm are available to solve this issue. Implementation/Library in Python will also work.

> Sentences might contain little different spellings.

List of strings has 10000-15000 strings.

Comment: Hint: `str_a in str_b` is `True` if string `str_a` is in string `str_b`

Comment: Spelling can be a little different in sentence. Also list has lots of strings, so checking every string from list is not feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a slight modification of standard problem of finding occurrences of set of words in a given input text. This problem can be efficiently solved by [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) Algorithm. You can modify the source codes available for the algorithm to match you needs.
Though sub-string functions can help you as answered by others but they work on small inputs. For larger input strings you will needed some linear time algorithm.

Comment: should note, that finding `exact` strings is Passe ;), the Diff-Match-Patch Library from Google has many great tools to find similar strings too.

Comment: @TomerW OP didn't say exact, thats why I said that slight modification is needed in the Algorithm. Libraries you can always use but knowing its good if you can also find algorithm behind it.

Answer (score 1):

As most of the answers here focus on string search part, I will consider the other interesting part of the problem, i.e. Spell Error.

Spell error case is an interesting and very practical in real data.

To deal with it, you can have a look at following metrics :

1. [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) : Its a string metric to measure the similarity between two strings. Its basically the min. number of single character edits(insertion, deletion, replace etc), u can do to transform one string to another.

   For ex :

   `"green in gold", "grren in gold" : Distane = 1 // replace r by e`

   Python package : [Levenstein Distance](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/)
2. [Soundex :](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) Generally spelling problems are solved by using some variation of Soundex Algorithm. Soundex is a phonetic algorithm for indexing names by sound, as pronounced in English. The goal is for homophones to be encoded to the same representation so that they can be matched despite minor differences in spelling. (Source Wiki )

   For ex : Soundex(Clinton) = Soundex(Clenton)

   Python library : [Fuzzy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fuzzy)

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure off the top of my head whether there's a faster solution, but the following shouldn't be too bad:

```
lower = sentence.lower()
for sub in list_of_string:
    if sub.lower() in sentence:
        print sub
```

I've converted both the sentence and the list to lowercase since you indicated by your example that you don't care about case. This will allow "Green" to match against "green", for example.

Answer (score 0):

I would turn your `list` into a `set` to improve performance. Then, you can do this:

```
list_of_strings = ['20th century women', 'green is gold ', 'fire at sea']
set_of_strings = set(s.strip().lower() for s in list_of_strings)

sentence = 'Official Trailer | Green is gold | Releasing Tomorrow'
parts = [i.strip() for i in sentence.split("|")]
for part in parts:
    if part.lower() in set_of_strings:
        print(part, "is a movie name")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for s in list_of_strings:
    if s in sentence:
        print 'found it!'
```

Your example sentence has a capital G in `Green is gold`, but the list of strings item has a lowercase g.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will take care of all caps, spaces, tabs cases:

```
for str in [str.lower().strip() for str in sentence.split(' | ')]:
    if str in [str.lower().strip() for str in list_of_strings]:
        print(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating over the list of strings and seeing if one of them is in the sentence. If it is, then return its index from the list.

```
for name in list_of_strings:
    if name in sentence:
        print list_of_strings.index(name)
```

Note you may want to analyse all strings (in list, and sentence) as lowercase (using the `.lower()` method) since capitalisation may be different between the two.